# Which SOFR rate to use and when?

Tags: sofr, risk-free-rate

When looking at the actual daily values provided by the SOFR API it's a bit confusing when/where to use which values given they provide two sets of values with different dates, SOFR on a T-1 basis and SOFRAI on a T basis.

ex: The values published at 8:30am on 2021-08-27 are as follows:

[image: SOFR 2021-08-26]

[image: SOFRAI 2021-08-27]

When I want daily discounting for 2021-08-26 on market close, do I need to wait to 8:30am on the following day or can I somehow use the SOFRAI values from 2021-08-26?